# Unqualified pseudo-destructor-name

Tags: c++, destructor, language-lawyer, pseudo-destructor

This simple program is accepted by EDG (ICC) but rejected by GCC and Clang.

Is it well formed? If not, why?

```
int main() {
    int n;
    n.~int();
}
```

<sub>To the curious: The program doesn't do anything and I rather doubt there's even a use case for this language feature. There's templates, but whether they generate expression syntax is debatable. Such topics aren't appropriate for this site. Nothing to see here.</sub>

---

**EDIT:** The title of this question is odd. I thought the issue was the lack of an `int::` qualifier before `~int`. The question was inspired by [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25365088/153285), which encourages omission of the qualifier when invoking something like `derived_object::~base_class()`. This however is ill-formed and [only accepted by GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60262).

Comment: Dang, I was about to take from a comment I read how long ago, but it's [your comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498730/why-is-c-not-an-object-oriented-language/3544556#comment3655901_3498750).

Comment: @chris Actually that's insightful, at that time I noted that a `typedef int INT` was needed "for syntax sake." And indeed, `int` is not a *type-name*.

Comment: The use case for this is `std::allocator::destroy()`.

Comment: @T.C. That's a template, and a two-phase template engine doesn't generate grammar productions upon instantiation. But, this is the topic I mentioned avoiding in the postscript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is ill-formed because `~int` is not a valid *pseudo-destructor-name*. According to the grammar at §5.2/1, in a *pseudo-destructor-name* the tilde must be followed by a *type-name* or *decltype-specifier*. A *type-name* is a *class-name*, *enum-name*, *typedef-name*, or *simple-template-id* (§7.1.6.2/1), and `int` is none of these, so `int` is not a *type-name* (although it is a *type-specifier*).

(References taken from N3936, *i.e.* the C++14 draft.)

Comment: You won the race! As posted answers go, at least :) .

Answer (score 3):

A *pseudo-destructor-name* is (§5.2 [expr.post]/p1):

```
pseudo-destructor-name:
    nested-name-specifier_opt type-name :: ~ type-name
    nested-name-specifier template simple-template-id :: ~ type-name
    nested-name-specifier_opt~ type-name
    ~ decltype-specifier
```

A *type-name* is (§7.1.6.2 [dcl.type.simple]/p1):

```
type-name:
    class-name
    enum-name
    typedef-name
    simple-template-id
```

Hence, `int` is not a *type-name*, so `n.~int();` is not well-formed.

Comment: Doesn't 5.2.4/2 say that the types shall be of scalar type, which is what `int` is?

Comment: @0x499602D2 `int` isn't a *type-name*, so `~int` doesn't even get past the syntax check, and the semantic constraints on the type don't even come into play.

Answer (score 2):

The *pseudo-destructor-name* grammar productions all require *type-name* identifiers, not *simple-type-specifiers* which is what `int` is.

So, this is an EDG bug, which is unusual.